# Why is there extra space at the top of my div?

Tags: html, css

BEFORE YOU SAY THIS IS A DUPLICATE
I have tried the margin-top: 0px;

```html
  <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    html, body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    }
    body {
    font: 22px trebuchet ms;
    }
    button {
    color: white;
    font: 18px verdana;
    background-color: #aef731;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #96d626;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 7px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    padding: 5px;
    }
    button:active {
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
    }
    button:focus {
    outline: none;
    }
    div.title {
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #96d626;
    }
    cat.indent {
    padding-left: 30px;
    }
    img.slgm {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-width: 4px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    }
    div.txt1 {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-width: 4px;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 600px;
    }
    div.txt2 {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-width: 4px;
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="title"><h1>60 Second Science!</h1><cat class="indent">Molecules of Solids, Liquids and Gases</cat></div>
    <img src="SLGM.png" class="slgm">
    <div class="txt1"><h3>Introduction</h3>Solids, liquids and gases all have different molecular structures. Today, we will explore each form of matter's molecules.<br><h3>Solids</h3>Solids(left) have a very compact structure. The molecules squish together and barely vibrate.<br><h3>Liquids</h3>Molecules in liquids(center) can move freely but stay bond together causing them to have a definite volume, but not a definite shape.</div>
    <div class="txt2"><h3>Gases</h3>Gases(right) have no definite shape or volume. This is because their molecular structure is very spacious. The particles have broke free of each other. Therefore, the gas can expand.</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

So when I run this code, the div with the class "txt2" has a bunch of space at the top. Could someone please help? I have also tried removing padding at the top, rewriting the code, etc. I need this done very soon so any response helps!

:D

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `div.txt2` has the rule `top: 200px`, which would explain the extra height. I've changed this to `top: 30px` to match the height of your other `<div>` in my example.

Also note that many of your elements have a fixed `width` of several hundred pixels. This won't scale on mobile devices, and you should consider using percentage-based values instead.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    body {
      font: 22px trebuchet ms;
    }
    
    button {
      color: white;
      font: 18px verdana;
      background-color: #aef731;
      border-style: solid;
      border-bottom-color: #96d626;
      border-width: 0px;
      border-bottom-width: 7px;
      border-radius: 12px;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    button:active {
      border-bottom-width: 0px;
      position: relative;
      top: 7px;
    }
    
    button:focus {
      outline: none;
    }
    
    div.title {
      padding-left: 15px;
      color: white;
      background-color: #96d626;
    }
    
    cat.indent {
      padding-left: 30px;
    }
    
    img.slgm {
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #000000;
      border-width: 4px;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      top: 30px;
      left: 30px;
    }
    
    div.txt1 {
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #000000;
      border-width: 4px;
      background-color: #e8e8e8;
      float: right;
      position: relative;
      top: 30px;
      right: 30px;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 600px;
    }
    
    div.txt2 {
      border-style: solid;
      border-color: #000000;
      border-width: 4px;
      background-color: #e8e8e8;
      width: 400px;
      position: relative;
      /*top: 200px;*/
      top: 30px;
      left: 30px;
      padding: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="title">
    <h1>60 Second Science!</h1>
    <cat class="indent">Molecules of Solids, Liquids and Gases</cat>
  </div>
  <img src="SLGM.png" class="slgm">
  <div class="txt1">
    <h3>Introduction</h3>Solids, liquids and gases all have different molecular structures. Today, we will explore each form of matter's molecules.<br>
    <h3>Solids</h3>Solids(left) have a very compact structure. The molecules squish together and barely vibrate.<br>
    <h3>Liquids</h3>Molecules in liquids(center) can move freely but stay bond together causing them to have a definite volume, but not a definite shape.</div>
  <div class="txt2">
    <h3>Gases</h3>Gases(right) have no definite shape or volume. This is because their molecular structure is very spacious. The particles have broke free of each other. Therefore, the gas can expand.</div>
</body>

</html>
```